# google cloud endpoints returning java long as string in JSON

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using google app engine latest version 1.9.30 and I define my cloud endpoint as follows

```
@Api(name="app", version="v1", transformers={EndpointDateTransformer.class})
public class MyEndpoints {

    @ApiMethod(name="dummy", path="dummy", httpMethod=HttpMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, Object> dummy(){
        Map<String, Object> dummy = Maps.newHashMap();
        dummy.put("date", DateUtil.getCurrentTimestamp());
        dummy.put("number", 5L);
        return dummy;
    }

}
```

here EndpointDateTransformer converts Date to Long value and the JSON response from endpoint is

```
{
    "number": "5",
    "date": "1452751174672"
}
```

But if I change that 5L to 5 then I see JSON response as

```
{
    "number": 5,
    "date": "1452751174672"
}
```

Why cloud endpoints converting Long values as string in JSON. When I was working on old app engine versions 1.9.19 it used to work. Long rendered as long on JSON as well. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Have you tried to use your map as `Map<String, Long>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSON is JavaScript Object Notation, it's a valid Javascript actually. So it should follow javascript standards.

Javascript's Number is 54 bit number, from `-(2^53 - 1)` to `(2^53 - 1)`. But Java's long is 64 bit number, from `-2^63` to `2^63-1`.

See difference:

```
Java Long Max         = 9223372036854775807
Javascript Number Max = 9007199254740992
```

You simply cannot convert Java Long to Javascript Number because it doesn't work for all values. So a string representation is used instead.

You have two possible solutions:

- define your value as `Integer`
- use an entity object with custom transformer, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apitransformer

Or if you really want Date, it's better to format it as `yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss` within UTC timezone. It's compatible with Javascript date format.

Specs:

- Javascript - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number
- Java - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html
- Javascript Date - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date